# How to select item from 2 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays `a` and `b` that contain some data. I also have an array `select` that I wish to use to select from either a or b. I was just wondering if there is a pythonic way to do so. Here is my current implementation which puts each row of a and b into a list then selects from it.

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(10,2,1,3,4))
b = np.ones(shape=(10,2,1,3,4))

select = [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

c = []
for a1,b1,select1 in zip(a,b,select):
    a1b1 = [a1,b1]
    c.append(a1b1[select])
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` is a very efficient solution but only works for up to two arrays.

I'd do it this way:

```
np.stack((a, b))[select, np.arange(len(a))]
```

This should scale to any number of arrays, e.g.:

```
a = ...
b = ...
# ...
z = ...
select = [0, 13, 2, 5, 25, ...]
np.stack((a, b, ... z))[select, np.arange(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose only from two arrays, you can use `select` as a weight:

```
w = np.array(select)
c = (a.T * w + b.T * (1 - w)).T
```

This hack does not work if you want to combine more than two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [512]: a = np.zeros(shape=(10,2,1,3,4)) 
     ...: b = np.ones(shape=(10,2,1,3,4)) 
     ...:  
     ...: select = [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

Using transpose in the same way that @DYZ does:

```
In [513]: res = np.where(select, a.T, b.T).T                                    
In [514]: res.shape                                                             
Out[514]: (10, 2, 1, 3, 4)
```

If you don't want to transpose, you could add dimensions to `select` so that it broadcasts to the same shape as `a` and `b`:

```
In [516]: res1 = np.where(np.array(select)[:,None,None,None,None],a,b)          
In [517]: res1.shape                                                            
Out[517]: (10, 2, 1, 3, 4)
In [518]: np.allclose(res,res1)                                                 
Out[518]: True
```